# how many users can visit a flask site at one time?

Tags: python, flask, webserver

I am surprised at how many different/evasive answers there are to this question. How many different people from around the world can be on my flask website at the same time?

Comment: It depends on the number of webworkers/threads you are having for your app. The requests are queued by NGINX and the threading/multiprocessing handles the requests.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "at the same time" you mean simultaneous requests (i.e., between receiving a request and completing a response), it's largely question of what resource (CPU/memory/bandwidth/disk) gets exhausted first. And that depends on lots of things, including available memory/cpu/bandwidth on the server, "size" and cpu appetite of your app, how many uwsgi/gunicorn servers you can fit into memory, how responsive back-end services such as databases are under load, etc. This isn't specific to Flask.